# How to add line break to text field in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I have the MEMO field of sales order pulled into the printed invoice (PDF). I want the string of the memo field to be split in multiple lines on the document.

MEMO "Line1 Line2" should result in

Line1

Line2

in the PDF

I tried "Line1\nLine", "Line1
Line" with all combination of quotes and escape backslashes. Wihtout luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you need line break on Advance PDF use the HTML tag `<br/>` or `<br>`.

If your Memo field contains `\n` you can replace it with `<br/>` in the advanced PDF using the following function

`${memo?replace("\n", "<br/>")}`